# Breakpoint not getting hit due to symbols not been loaded

Tags: javascript, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, winjs

I am trying to debug an issue with my JavaScript based Windows 8 Store app related to search activation. I have re-build and deployed again on my machine but for some reason the breakpoint in the activated method is not getting hit. It shows me message that "The breakpoint will not currently get hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document". Any idea what I may be doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Are you attached to a release build or debug build?
Go to the Debug-Modules window and see what your symbols show for loading for your program's name. It may help to clean from visual studio, remove the app, rebuild and debug again. Also set a breakpoint in your default.js to ensure anything is getting hit.

Comment: For some reason, I stopped getting this issue but if I get it again, I will try your suggestion :)

Comment: usually it does resolve itself :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're set to debug managed code and not script. Sometimes also being set to debug both managed and script will also cause this behavior.

In your HTML project's properties, navigate to the *Debugging* section and select *Script Only*. Please note that this will disable Managed code debugging, so you have to choose between debugging managed libraries or Scripts at a time. The following screenshot shows this setting.

[image]

<sup><sub>Image/parts of the steps borrowed from this post: http://www.silverlightrecipes.com/2012/04/windows-8-quick-tip-debugging-managed.html</sub></sup>